# React useState toggle single button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple buttons in a react component that will allow me to show or hide some piece of data based on which ever button I click. I have a toggle animation that will set two different icon states (show & hide)

#### set state

Here's how I set my state: `const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);`

#### handle click

The function that toggles the click event

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    setClicked(s => !s);
  };
```

#### button toggle

```
          <Button className={style.selector} onClick={handleClick}>
            {clicked ? (
              <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
            ) : (
              <img src={on} alt="visible" />
            )}
            {
              <FormattedMessage
                id="side_properties"
                defaultMessage={"BUTTON 1"}
              />
            }
          </Button>

      // other buttons below with the same format.
```

The toggle icon function works, however when a single button is clicked, the icon changes on all of the remaining buttons. How do I limit this click event to a single button?

Comment: How about `setClicked(!clicked)` ?

Comment: Why don't make a button component? You don't need to handle arrays then.

Comment: @O.o it sounds like it's some sort of a filter mechanism that depending on which buttons are clicked, it will show a different result, so you will still have to keep track of that `state` in the `parent` component even if you created a separate `Button` component so that tracks it's own clicked `state` - you'd still need an array inside `parent`.

Comment: No, if we use ref, we can get child state from parent. no need to handle array state.

Comment: @O.o that's not what `refs` should be used for - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs - "avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep track of `state` for each `button` in an `array` and update each button individually.

Here's a possible solution:

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const initialState = Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, idx) => {
    return { id: idx + 1, clicked: false };
  });
  const [buttons, setButtons] = React.useState(initialState);

  function handleButtonClick(buttonId) {
    const nextState = buttons.map(button => {
      if (button.id !== buttonId) {
        return button;
      }
      return { ...button, clicked: !button.clicked };
    });
    setButtons(nextState);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(button => (
        <button
          key={button.id}
          type="button"
          onClick={() => handleButtonClick(button.id)}
        >
          [{button.id}] {button.clicked ? "Clicked" : "Not clicked"}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a working example if you'd like to see:

- [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-khorana-d2hku?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Thank you. I had looked at the other answers which were also and realized that I could just put all the button states in JSON as true or false. This answer reduces the amount of code to write for each button.

Comment: @RHBlanchfield looks like the other answers had declared state for each button manually, and if you have a lot of buttons this would definitely be a pain to write. Just use an array and pass the unique identifier to know which button was clicked and should be changed, just like in my example. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define some kind of enum for your state like this:

```
const btnState = {
  normal: 0,
  btn1Clicked: 1,
  btn2Clicked: 2,
}
```

and then use in your state like this:

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(btnState.normal);
```

and your button would be like this:

```
          <Button className={style.selector} onClick={e => handleClick(btnState.btn1Clicked)}>
            {clicked === btnState.btn1Clicked ? (
              <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
            ) : (
              <img src={on} alt="visible" />
            )}
            {
              <FormattedMessage
                id="side_properties"
                defaultMessage={"BUTTON 1"}
              />
            }
          </Button>
```

and your `handleClick` would be like this:

```
  const handleClick = (state) => {
    setClicked(state);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using the same state for all the buttons. You will need a state for each button separately.

```
const [button1Clicked, setButton1Clicked] = useState(false);
const [button2Clicked, setButton2Clicked] = useState(false);
...
```

Then for each button,

```
          <Button className={style.selector} onClick={() => setButton1Clicked(s => !s);}>
            {clicked ? (
              <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
            ) : (
              <img src={on} alt="visible" />
            )}
            {
              <FormattedMessage
                id="side_properties"
                defaultMessage={"BUTTON 1"}
              />
            }
          </Button>
```

You could also use an object or array as a state instead of having one variable per button.

```
const buttons = ['button1', 'button2',...] //Consider using meaningful names here
const [buttonStates, setButtonStates] = useState(buttons.reduce((accum, currVal) => ({
  ...accum,
  [currVal]: false
}), {}));

const handleClick = (buttonName) => {
  setClicked(s => ({
    ...s,
    [buttonName]: !s[buttonName]
  })); 
};
```

Then for each button,

```
          <Button className={style.selector} onClick={() => handleClick('button1')}>
            {clicked ? (
              <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
            ) : (
              <img src={on} alt="visible" />
            )}
            {
              <FormattedMessage
                id="side_properties"
                defaultMessage={"BUTTON 1"}
              />
            }
          </Button>
```

Note that you should change the 'button1' to the name of each button.

Answer (score 0):

It is because all your button text is based on one state variable. There are multiple approaches to tackle this. 
If you only want to have one active button at a time:

```
const buttonMap = {
    button1: 'button1',
    button2: 'button2',
}

const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(); // Default button which you want to be clicked

const handleClick = (button) => {
    setClicked(button);
};

<Button 
     onClick={e => handleClick(buttonMap.button1)}
>
    {
        clicked === buttonMap.button1 ? (
          <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
        ) : (
          <img src={on} alt="visible" />
        )
    }

</Button>
```

If you want multiple buttons to be acive at once... You need to use different state properties for each button... For this, you can have multiple state variables for each button or you can have an object for the state where keys of the object will inform if the button is clicked or not.

```
const intialButtonState = {
    button1: false,
    button2: false,
}

const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(intialButtonState); // Default button which you want to be clicked

const handleClick = (button) => {
    setClicked({...clicked, [button]: !clicked[button]});
};

<Button 
     onClick={e => handleClick('button1')}
>
    {
        clicked.button1 ? (
          <img src={off} alt="hidden" />
        ) : (
          <img src={on} alt="visible" />
        )
    }

</Button>
```